# Why Toolbar disappeared?

Tags: android, xml, toolbar

I can't really understand, why my `Toolbar` disappeared, something should there be wrong. As you can see, toolbar is there, but somehow looks like transparent.

[image]

The same bug is in the app after running, but there it is totally invisible.

[image]

I'm using a custom Toolbar in my MainActivity because of Navigation Drawer:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_main"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:elevation="4dp"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <include
        android:id="@+id/content_main"
        layout="@layout/content_main" />

    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view_main"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/colorAccent"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:menu="@menu/drawer_menu_main" />

</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

And my MainActivity class looks like this:

```
    private lateinit var drawerLayout: DrawerLayout

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val toolbar: Toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar_main)
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar)

        drawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout_main)
        val navView: NavigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view_main)
        val toggle = ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this,
            drawerLayout,
            toolbar,
            R.string.navigation_drawer_open,
            R.string.navigation_drawer_close
        )
        drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(toggle)
        toggle.syncState()

        navView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this)
    }
```

Also, I use a custom style with NoActionBar defined as:

```
    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
    </style>
```

and of course applied in Manifest for this particular activity:

```
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

The thing is firstly, I want to use a non-transparent Toolbar and secondly, I worked before, but during programming I noticed that I doesn't work/appear any more. How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Move the `<include>` into the `<LinearLayout>`, after the `<Toolbar>`.

Comment: @MikeM. You are awesome, man! I worked after moving as you proposed. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

The solution was found. Please refer to MikeM.'s comment above.

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_main"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:elevation="4dp"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

        <include
            android:id="@+id/content_main"
            layout="@layout/content_main" />
    </LinearLayout>
```